# Which "ripple" definition could be applied to this article?

Tags: difference

I am currently reading [**this article.**](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/global-macro-trader-who-nailed-the-2008-crisis-says-next-3-months-mark-edge-of-the-cliff-for-marketsand-were-there-right-now-2019-08-07?siteid=yhoof2&yptr=yahoo)  and there is a line, which is,

> Pal says the U.S. dollar’s relative strength, measured on a trade-weighted basis, is **rippling** around the world, particularly as global central banks adopt easy-money policies that appear to be more accommodative than even the U.S. Federal Reserve, driving local currencies lower against the buck.

It is easy for me to understand this is the intransitive. But there are many definitions according to the Merriam Unabrided, which are,

> dialectal, British
>   :  to scratch slightly

I don't think this can't be applicable considering the preceding and following context. And there is another, which is,

> 1>a :  to become fretted or lightly ruffled on the surface (as water) :  become covered with or form in small waves or undulations
>
> b :  to flow in small waves
>
> c :  to fall in soft undulating folds or wavy lines
>
> 2
>   :  to flow with a light rise and fall of sound or inflection
>
> 3
>   :  to move with an undulating motion or so as to cause ripples
>
> 4
>   :  to run irregularly through a crowd, group, or population

Personally feeling, one of the above definitions would be a candidate, but the truth is unknown to me.

Could you teach me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense hre is close to 1b or 3, but it is a figurative use, while those seem to be literal senses. The movement of money or of interest rates around the world is being compared to the movement of ripples over the surface of a lake or other small body of water. "ripple" is chose rather than "wave" to suggest that individual changes are amall, but that they propagate from one place to another like waves or ripples.